# jQuery Hover Menu disappears when right click

Tags: jquery, hover, contextmenu, show-hide, right-click

I have a Menu that opens when hovering. But on right click the menu disappears when the contextmenu opens. But I can't figure out why. I need the hover menu open at the same time with contextmenu/right click.

The jQuery Code (Version jquery-1.11.2.min.js) :

```
    jQuery(document).on('mouseover','#main_menu',function() {

        jQuery('#main_menu_inner').show();

    });
    jQuery(document).on('mouseleave','#main_menu',function() {

        jQuery('#main_menu_inner').hide();

    });
```

The HTML:

```
<div id="main_menu">
    <img id="menu_button" src="/skin/images/all/structure/menu_button.png" alt="Men&uuml;" />
    <div id="main_menu_inner">
        <img id="menu_arrow" src="/skin/images/all/structure/main_menu_arrow_down.png" alt="Arrow" />
        <div class="clear_right"></div>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="">Link</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `mouseleave` => `hide`

Comment: Hmm but when I remove the mouseleave code the menu stays when the mouse is leaving.

Comment: Well, you need to work out the logic here. And I'm afraid that's something the community can't help you with.

Comment: The items are nested, so the `events` are bubbling. Give it a search and you'll get yourself sorted out.

Answer (score 2):

You can "hack" the `mouseover`/`mouseleave` behaviour by adding a boolean to check if the context menu is opened into the `mouseleave` event handler. That's not a really good practice, but it makes your request possible:

```
var contextMenuOpened = false;

$(document).on('mouseover', '#main_menu', function () {
    $('#main_menu_inner').show();
    contextMenuOpened = false;
});

$(document).on('mouseleave', '#main_menu', function () {
    $("#main_menu").on('contextmenu', function (e) {
        contextMenuOpened = true;
    });
    if (!contextMenuOpened) {
        $('#main_menu_inner').hide();
    }
});
```

> [Live exemple](https://jsfiddle.net/9wqqc3n7/)

Comment: Is is a bad idea to register the `$("#main_menu").on('contextmenu'` for every `mouseleave`. If you leave the `#main_menu` e.g. tree times then the there are tree callbacks registered for `#main_menu` doing the same thing.