# jQuery mouseleave() and context menu issue in Mozilla

Tags: jquery, mouseleave

On my site I have a floating contact form which shows up after clicking an icon. When mouse leaves the contact form it's supposed to close. And it works fine.
The problem is that in Mozilla when one wants to paste a text to the contact form via context menu the form closes - I do right click, want to choose 'paste' and then it closes. How should I change my jQuery function to avoid that? The problem appears only in Mozilla.

And my jQuery (it's probably very poorly written, I've just started to learn):

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 jQuery(document).ready(function($){    
      $('#order-icon').click(function() {
           $('#floating-form').addClass("open");
      });

      $('#order-icon').mouseover(function() {
                $(this).addClass("hover");
      });

      $('#order-icon').mouseleave(function() {
           $(this).removeClass("hover");
      });

      $('#floating-form').mouseleave(function() {
           $(this).removeClass("open");
      });

      $('#floating-form').contextmenu(function() {
           $(this).addClass("open");
      });

      var body = $( 'body' );
 });
</script>
```

The floating form structure:

```
     <div id="floating-form">
           <div id="order-form">
               <!-- contact form -->
           </div>
           <div id="order-icon">
               <!-- icon -->  
           </div>
      </div>
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: There are different questions targeting this: [Is there a close event for the browser contextmenu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12801898) and [jQuery Hover Menu disappears when right click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29693979), but both of them do not work reliable. The second one is even wrong,

Comment: The main problem is that IMHO there is no reliable way to check if the context menu was closed. Otherwise you could stop the listening to the mouseleave event when the contextmenu opens, and the after close start the listeners again and check if the mouse is still within the `floating-form`

Answer (score 0):

support all browser (included Firefox) :

```
<html oncontextmenu="menuShow(event)" contextmenu="floating-form">

<script>
function menuShow(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 $("#floating-form").addClass("open");
}
</script>
```

Comment: If I understand the OP correctly the context menu should open so that users can use it to past data into the form fields.

Comment: yes, @t.niese is right. This code doesn't work for me unfortunately.